# create button add delete edit jqgrid

Tags: javascript, html, css, jqgrid

I have created a jqgrid, and I was successful in creating add,delete,edit function by enabling these functions which belong to the jqgrid library. I want to create button add,delete,edit functions outside the table and here is my code:

```
    <table id="list47"></table>
<div id="plist47"></div>

<script>

    var mydata = JSON.parse('@DATA_QUERIED'),
        editSettings = {
            checkOnUpdate: true,
            reloadAfterSubmit: false,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            savekey: [true, 13],
            closeAfterEdit: true
        },
        addSettings = {
            checkOnUpdate: true,
            reloadAfterSubmit: false,
            savekey: [true, 13],
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true
        },
        delSettings = {
            onclickSubmit: function () {
                var $this = $(this), p = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam"), newPage = p.page;

                if (p.lastpage > 1) {// on the multipage grid reload the grid
                    if (p.reccount === 1 && newPage === p.lastpage) {
                        // if after deliting there are no rows on the current page
                        // which is the last page of the grid
                        newPage--; // go to the previous page
                    }
                    // reload grid to make the row from the next page visable.
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: newPage }]);
                    }, 50);
                }

                return true;
            }
        },
        removeTheOptionAll = function (elem) {
            // We use "value" in the searchoption property of some columns of the colModel.
            // The option {"": "All"} neams "No filter" and should be displayed only
            // in the searching toolbar and not in the searching dialog.
            // So we use dataInit:removeTheOptionAll inside of searchoptions to remove
            // the option {"": "All"} in case of the searching dialog
            if (elem != null && typeof elem.id === "string" && elem.id.substr(0, 3) !== "gs_") {
                // we are NOT in the searching bar
                $(elem).find("option[value=\"\"]").remove(); // remove "All" option
            }
        };


    $(document).ready(function () {

        jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
            data: mydata,
            datatype: "local",
            autowidth: true,
            height: 'auto',
            rowNum: 15,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20],
            colNames: ['USER_ID', 'USER_NAME', 'LOGIN_NAME', 'PASSWORD', 'DESCRIPTION', 'GROUP_ID', 'EMAIL', 'ACTIVE', 'ORGANIZATION_ID'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'USER_ID', index: 'USER_ID', width: 100, },
                { name: 'USER_NAME', index: 'USER_NAME', width: 140,edittype: "textarea" },
                { name: 'LOGIN_NAME', index: 'LOGIN_NAME', width: 140,edittype: "textarea" },
                { name: 'PASSWORD', index: 'PASSWORD', width: 140,edittype: "textarea" },
                { name: 'DESCRIPTION', index: 'DESCRIPTION', width: 140,edittype: "textarea" },
                { name: 'GROUP_ID', index: 'GROUP_ID', width: 140,edittype: "textarea" },
                { name: 'EMAIL', index: 'EMAIL', width: 200,edittype: "textarea" },
                { name: 'ACTIVE', index: 'ACTIVE', width: 70, sorttype: "float",formatter: "number", editable: true },
                { name: 'ORGANIZATION_ID', index: 'RGANIZATION_IDz', width: 140, sorttype: "float",formatter: "number", editable: true }
            ],
            cmTemplate: {editable: true, searchoptions: {clearSearch: false }},
            pager: "#plist47",
            viewrecords: true,
            sortname: 'USER_ID',
            gridview: true,
            grouping: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            autoencode: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            caption: "Đây là ví dụ mẫu về Grid",
            ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
                    var $this = $(this), selRowId = $this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
                    if (selRowId !== rowid) {
                        // prevent the row from be unselected on double-click
                        // the implementation is for "multiselect:false" which we use,
                        // but one can easy modify the code for "multiselect:true"
                        $this.jqGrid("setSelection", rowid);
                    }
                    $this.jqGrid("editGridRow", rowid, editSettings);
                }
        }).jqGrid("navGrid", "#plist47", {}, editSettings, addSettings, delSettings, {
                multipleSearch: true,
                overlay: false,
                onClose: function () {
                    // if we close the search dialog during the datapicker are opened
                    // the datepicker will stay opened. To fix this we have to hide
                    // the div used by datepicker
                    $("div#ui-datepicker-div.ui-datepicker").hide();
                }
            }).jqGrid("filterToolbar", { defaultSearch: "cn" });

    });
</script>
```

here is the picture of that code: [picture 1](https://ibb.co/CB17jhv)
So I have add del edit at the bottom of the jqgrid, now I want to create a button outside jqgrid like:

[picture 2](https://ibb.co/CzFfkt1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the methods for insert, update delete. For update or delete you will need to get the selected id and call the method. By example the code for edit a row can look like this.

```
$("#button_edit").click( function() {
    var selcted_row = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    if(selected_row) {
        $("#grid").jqGrid("editGridRow",selected_row, editSettings);
    } else {
        alert("please select row");
    }
});
```

Do similar to delete and adding a row. Look at the documentation for the methods.

Comment: How can I do it with Bootstrap 4 modal?
I need to create my own form right?
Then how can I link that form with my jqgrid?

Comment: Do you have any guild or some example for it ?